# How do I know how "PvP scaling" affects my build in Hall of Grandmasters?

Tags: path-of-exile

[Hall of Grandmasters](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Hall_of_Grandmasters) has the modifier "PvP damage scaling in effect".

How can I see how this affects my build (and thus see if I can reasonably expect to clear the map)?

Comment: From looking at the wiki it seems that each individual skill has it's own scaling for PVP. Unless Path of building has a PVP scaling option, you're going to have to do the math manually. You can find the info here https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Player_versus_player